# How to get metadata from video-movie file using Objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, video, metadata

Any help? Now can get NSSize, duration and its all.

Comment: What kind of metadata?  Spotlight metadata, or metadata that's embedded in the file itself?

Comment: Objective-C does not provide any such functionality. Are you using any application framework that might be relevant (e.g. Cocoa, iPhone SDK)?

Comment: In the file itself. Because i need to get metadata from network disks.

Cocoa. Yes, i already know it, and spend much time in digging frameworks, especialy QT, but no results6 there only audio meta data +  duration + NSSize of video, but no video bit Rate, codecs..

Answer (score 5):

You can do this almost entirely using Spotlight's metadata.

For example, I do the following in one of my apps

```
MDItemRef fileMetadata=MDItemCreate(NULL,(CFStringRef)eachPath);
NSDictionary *metadataDictionary = (NSDictionary*)MDItemCopyAttributes (fileMetadata,
                                                                                           (CFArrayRef)[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)kMDItemPixelHeight,(id)kMDItemPixelWidth,nil]);
```

This code essentially asks for the pixel width and height for a movie file (to determine if it's the dimension of an HD movie or not is the reason).

The Spotlight Metadata Attributes Reference lists all the available keys for various file types by category. You can probably get the required data this way without doing anything significant, provided that the media type you're examining has a Spotlight plug-in.

Answer (score 4):

This functionality may not be built in (I'm honestly not sure), but I do know of two third-party libraries which can tell you the information you need.

- [VLCKit](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLCKit), the framework being used by the newest beta versions of VLC for Mac.
- [libmediainfo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mediainfo/files/binary/libmediainfo0/), a multi-purpose library that can read practically any bit of information you need out of practically any media file.

I can go into more depth with how to use either of these, but I'd rather only do so if you end up needing me to. Let me know!

Comment: test app based on libmediainfo looks pretty good, but i really can't understand how to use it in my project. If you did any objective-c project with this library i would be very appreciative if you share this project with me^ or f you did not objective-c project when just give me some hints how to include and use this library in my project.

Comment: To start out, you'll want to download the MediaInfo dylib. Follow the link above, and find this file:  MediaInfo_DLL_0.7.33_Mac_Universal.tar. Download it.

Add the .dylib file to your project. If there is more than one dylib in the folder, add the one that is largest.

Make sure the dylib file is added to your target's "Link Binary with Libraries" build phase. Then add the path to the Developers/Include directory from the downloaded folder to your Header Search Paths in Xcode. You can then #import "MediaInfoDLL.h" in your code, and follow the included documentation for how to open files.