# Objective-C - How to load DLL and use it

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to use the MediaInfo DLL in a Mac application but with no success. I have followed all the steps indicated by Carter Allen on this question [How to get metadata from video-movie file using Objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023954/how-to-get-metadata-from-video-movie-file-with-using-objective-c)

I've imported #import "MediaInfoDLL/MediaInfoDLL.h" but I don't know how to actually use that class in my code.

The class name is MediaInfo and the method I need is Open. I imagine it must be something really basic...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, OS X doesn't have DLLs or, at least, they aren't called that (generally, you use a bundle to contain dynamically loaded code -- see `NSBundle`).  I'm guessing you come from a Windows background?

The documentation for the MediaInfo SDK does not indicate anything about support for OS X.  However, they do have a OS X version of the GUI and, thus, the code at least works on OS X.

Sounds like you'll need to port the library portion to an OS X Bundle and then load it.  Or, better yet, if you are writing an OS X application, just add the relevant sources to your application's project.

Or do a google search;  there are quite likely more native, already supported, Objective-C APIs for doing the same.

Comment: They're called `.dylib` files by convention.

Comment: Which means that, if he actually **has** a DLL, it can't be used on OS X.

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember why I called it DLL, but it is actually a .dylib file. I imported it and and I get no errors, so I think the only part I am missing is the actual creation of the object. I think the library is not written in objective-c, so I guess I'll have to create the object using the library language syntax... (?)

Comment: No worries;   yes -- if there is a dylib, then you should be able to #include the header files containing the dylib's API and call the API provided therein, regardless of whether it is written in Objective-C, C or C++.

Comment: Thank you bbum, I've done what you said, but when I create my object with the following code xCode says "Use of undeclared identifier 'MediaInfo'": 'MediaInfo *mi = [[MediaInfo alloc] init];'

Comment: Did you #include the header file that defines `MediaInfo`?