# How to accesing metadata from video file in Objective-C (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, video, metadata

How to extract from video, it duration, codecs, size and more information ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023954/how-to-get-metadata-from-video-movie-file-with-using-objective-c?rq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the AV Foundation framework.

[*AV Foundation Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188)
[*AV Foundation Framework Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/_index.html)