# finding video creation date on .mov file that has been emailed.

Tags: iphone, email, date, video, .mov

I am trying to put a date to a .mov video file that was recorded with an iphone and then sent, presumably from the phone itself, via email. The creation date on the video seems to be the date it was sent (I checked this by sending an old video to myself and it held true) rather than the date it was originally created. Is there some way around this or am I screwed?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035245/how-to-accesing-metadata-from-video-file-in-objective-c-ios

Comment: AVFoundation stuff is going to give you the modification date as well.

Comment: Is the phone re-encoding the video before sending it (annoying but would not surprise me), or is it simply attaching it to the message?